# XML serialization / deserialization names and Inheritance

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I'm getting the following error during deserialization:

Types 'MyLib.Xml.CompanyDetails' and 'MyApp.Web.Models.CompanyDetails' both use the XML type name, 'CompanyDetails', from namespace 'http://xml.domain.com/schema'. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I can fix the issue using different class names as show below, but I don't want to...

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CompanyDetails", Namespace = "http://xml.domain.com/schema/schema")]
public class CompanyDetailsXX : MyLib.Xml.CompanyDetails
```

I use inheritance as I'm not able to change the base class and need to add extra properties (not populated during deserialization)

I want the base and parent class to have the same names, as it makes sense like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CompanyDetails", Namespace = "http://xml.domain.com/schema/schema")]
    public class CompanyDetails : MyLib.Xml.CompanyDetails
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a different XML element name for your child type.

You created a different class name for your child class in C#, didn't you?  The same requirement applies to XML types.  An XML child type cannot have the same name as its parent.

This is especially true when both the parent and the child objects are being streamed out to XML, as seems to be indicated by the error message you posted.